# Using AWK To extract data when a condition is met?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have a large file that has some regular pattern

```
   snaps1:          Counter:             4966
    Opens:          Counter:           357283
 Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.mount275668.attributes

   snaps1:          Counter:             0
    Opens:          Counter:           357283
 Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.test.attributes
```

These line are repeated among other lines above and below. I need to print the snaps1 line and also get the instance: line So I need to search for snaps1 but only if counter is greater than 0 and then print snaps1 line and also the instance line.

Someone from this site provided the answer

```
 awk '/snaps1/{s=$0; c=$NF} /Instance/ && c{print s ORS $0}' file
```

This works , but I am not sure how it works. I also need to know if this gets rid of the spaces? ANd what if I want to compare a text rather than zero above . So instead of looking for zero I will be looking for snap1 where it is only equal to ZZZ  and I want to print  line containing instance as the answer provided above when comparing for snap1 > zero. Can someone please reply and PLEASE provide details of how this works so I can use it other places?

```
   snaps1:          Counter:             ZZZ
    Opens:          Counter:           357283
 Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.test.attributes

   snaps1:          Counter:             ABC
    Opens:          Counter:           357283
 Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.test.attributes
```

So from the lines above I should see this output

```
snaps1:          Counter:             ZZZ
Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.test.attributes
```

Appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: The ` && c` part checks that the counter was not 0.  So you could use `awk '/snaps1/{s=$0; c=$NF=="ZZZ"} /Instance/ && c{print s ORS $0}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
awk '/snaps1/ && $NF=="ZZZ"{s=$0} /Instance/ && s{print s ORS $0; s=""}' file
   snaps1:          Counter:             ZZZ
 Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.test.attributes
```

**Awk command breakdown:**

```
/snaps1/ && $NF=="ZZZ"  # if line has "snaps1" and last field is "ZZZ"
{s=$0}                  # store current line in variable s
/Instance/ && s         # if line has "Instance" and variable s is not empty
{print s ORS $0; s=""}  # print variable s ORS and current line. Reset variable s
```

Comment: Thanks so much what is ORS

Comment: `ORS` is output record separator. This is by default set to `\n`